# Localization with bean validation in JSF

Tags: java, jsf-2, localization, richfaces, bean-validation

I made a MVC based website using JSF 2.0 and RichFaces 4. Every input text validation is been done using bean validation annotations. I am using Hibernate Validator as bean validation implementation.

How can I display a localized message?

If I use

```
@NotNull(message="<h:outputText value=\"#{msg['Mymessage']}\" />")
```

then it literally displays `<h:outputText value="#{msg['Mymessage']}" />` as message.

[image]

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should and can not put JSF tags in the message. Also, JSF's own resource bundle won't be used to resolve localized validation messages. JSR303 bean validation is a completely separate API unrelated to JSF.

To internationalize JSR303 bean validation messages, you need to create a separate `ValidationMessages.properties` file in the classpath root which can be localized by `ValidationMessages_xx_XX.properties` files.

E.g.

```
ERVNomView=Your message here
```

Which is then to be specified with `{key}` syntax.

```java
@NotEmpty(message="{ERVNomView}")
```

#### See also:

- [Chapter 4.3.1.1 of the JSR303 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/edr/jsr303/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

For those of you having the same problem as me (the solution given by @BalusC wasn't working with many different properties files for many languages), the thing to do is to name all of the properties files in the following pattern:
ValidationMessages_xx.properties

I don't know why, but the pattern ...xx_XX... wasn't working for me.

Comment: The pattern `xx_XX` is for region specific locales, e.g. British English is `en_UK`, whereas `en` just stand for English in general. You should always have the general variant to fall back to, then it will work.