# How to localize Bean Validation messages

Tags: localization, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have a class and using annotation to validate the class properties.

My web page (jsf2.2/primefaces/maven) is multilanguage (DE-utch, FR-rench, IT-alian).

My problem is that the hibernate-validator has support for some languages(de, en, es, fr, hu, tr, pt_BR, mn_MN, zn_CN) but not Italian! (listed in the jar, org->hibernate->validator)
So when i use the Italian version of my web page the validation messages are shown in english(default choice of hibernate).

How i can override this, and provide custom italian validation messages?

I don't want to mess with the hibernate jar, because the project is maven and the jar is automatically fetched.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Managed to overcome this without messing with the hibernate jar.

---

If we want to override default `ValidationMessages.properties`:

1. We can pick the appropriate files (hint:copy them from the hibernate
   jar: `ValidationMessages.properties`,
   `ValidationMessages_de.properties`,
   `ValidationMessages_fr.properties`) and edit them accordingly.
2. Put all all in our project's **`src/main/resources`** folder. So
   the folder contains all the *.properties files.
3. *To provide validations for more languages (except of
   hibernate's default langs), f.e. the italian language, we create a
   `ValidationMessages_it.properties` and put it at **`src/main/resources`** folder. (**`src/main/resources/ValidationMessages_it.properties`**).

After all, when locale is set to italian language, hibernate will look first at latter folder, in case of any overridden/other validation messages (like  ValidationMessages_*.properties), and use them instead of default ones!

> **Caution**
>   This solution is for **MAVEN** project, otherwise you should put *properties.files at **`/src/main/java`** folder, [as mentioned in another similar question comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630589/overwriting-default-hibernate-validator-messages)

Comment: No need to extract anything. Just add the properties files you need or want to override. They need to be in the root of the classpath. User provided ValidationMessages properties file have precedence over the built-in ones.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide your own language file by putting the

```
 ValidationMessages_it_IT.properties
```

on your classpath.

This question is a duplicate of [Localization with bean validation in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915770/localization-with-bean-validation-in-jsf)

Answer (score 1):

Put properties files under src/main/resources folder, they should be named `ValidationMessages_{locale code}.properties`, the default one should be `ValidationMessages.properties` , the contents are looking like:

```
invalid.phone.number = Invalid phone number
```

Then in your bean:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]+[0-9\\-]{3,}[0-9]+$", message = "{invalid.phone.number}")
    private String number;
```